# Regex and textmatching issue

Tags: regex, postgresql, pattern-matching

I am doing some basic text matching in Postgres 9.3.5.0.
Here is my code so far:

```
  Select text from eightks
  WHERE other_events = true and 
  keywordRegexs = [\y(director and member \s+  and resigned)\y/ix];
```

I am getting the following errors

> ```
> psql:test3.sql:3: invalid command \y(director
> psql:test3.sql:5: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["
> LINE 3:  keywordRegexs = [
> ```

I am trying to find documents which contain those exact phrases.

Comment: As well as Erwin's point ... regular expressions are literals and must be quoted as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression match operator in Postgres is **`~`**.
The case insensitive variant is **`~*`**.
Branches are enclosed in `()`.

```
SELECT text
FROM   eightks
WHERE  other_events = true
AND    keywordregexs ~* '(\y(director | member \s+ |resigned)\y)';
```

The meaning of "those exact phrases" is not clear in the question.
[Details in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)

Comment: thanks @Erwinbrandstetter. I should have been more clear about the exact phrases. What i mean is want to documents which have the words, director and member and resigned.

Comment: @wazza2013 In that case, regular expression syntax supports word-boundary markers; you should probably use those.