# SQL Query to Transpose Column Counts to Row Counts

Tags: sql, postgresql, unpivot, unnest

I have a table that looks like the following which shows the count of types. I need to and have been trying to display data as 1 column and 7 rows instead though... without success.

> ```
> __________________________________________________________________________
> | col types      | win2k | winxp | win2k3 | vista | win7 | win8 | win8.1 |
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------
> | count of types |  2365 | 65655 | 422445 | 4822  | 482  | 2331 | 485323 |
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

```
Select 
count(case when col1 ~* '5.0.2195' then 1 else null end) as Win2k,
count(case when col1 ~* '5.1.2600' then 1 else null end) as WinXP, 
count(case when col1 ~* '5.2.3790' then 1 else null end) as W2k3,
count(case when (col1 ~* '6.0.6000'
    or col1 ~* '6.0.6001' or col1 ~* '6.0.6002') 
    then 1 else null end) as Vista,
count(case when (col1 ~* '6.1.7600'
    or col1 ~* '6.1.7601')
    then 1 else null end) as Win7,
count(case when col1 ~* '6.2.9200' then 1 else null end) as Win8,
count(case when (col1 ~* '6.3.9200'
    or col1 ~* '6.3.9600')
    then 1 else null end) as "Win8.1"
From col1
```

Ideally it would look something like this:

> ```
> ___________________
> | types  | count  |
> -------------------
> | win2k  | 2365   |
> | winxp  | 65655  |
> | win2k3 | 422445 | 
> | vista  | 4822   |
> | win7   | 482    |
> | win8   | 2331   |
> | win8.1 | 485323 |
> -------------------
> ```

Notes:

- I am using Postgresql 9.3 with PGADMIN III
- I cannot create any custom functions
- It wouldn't matter if there were more columns to make this work

Comment: possible duplicate of [unpivot and PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128737/unpivot-and-postgresql)

Comment: I think Bulat is correct, you want a (un)pivot table which is the opposite of http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tablefunc.html

Comment: Bulat, I looked and tried that reference before I posted and although it may seem similar, it has a different table/data structure that doesn't apply. My singular row is aggregated data making the unpivot very difficult if not impossible.

Comment: Of course it's possible. Your presented query is illegal and confusing, so it's hard to tell, what's best for you. `profile.foo` is not a legal column name in the context of your query. Pleae repair the question. You could provide the table definition and some sample values to clarify.

Comment: First question posted... still learning.

Comment: The question is misleading, @cha got into your mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These type of queries are easier to make with an aim of GROUP BY, like this:

```
Select 
case when profile.foo ~* '5.0.2195' then 'Win2k'
     when profile.foo ~* '5.1.2600' then 'WinXP' 
     when profile.foo ~* '5.2.3790' then 'W2k3'
     when (profile.foo ~* '6.0.6000'
        or profile.foo ~* '6.0.6001'
        or profile.foo ~* '6.0.6002') 
        then 'Vista'
     when (profile.foo ~* '6.1.7600'
        or profile.foo ~* '6.1.7601')
        then 'Win7'
     when profile.foo ~* '6.2.9200' then 'Win8'
     when (profile.foo ~* '6.3.9200'
        or profile.foo ~* '6.3.9600')
        then 'Win8.1' ELSE 'Other' END as type,
     count(*) as cnt
From profile
GROUP BY 1
```

As commented below this query will work for mutually exclusive cases, i.e. when `profile.foo` contains a value representing one OS per row

Comment: In the from statement, I removed the column name and it worked perfect. Thanks!

Comment: As commented on the other (equivalent and earlier) question, this answer is only valid for mutually exclusive cases. Simplify with `GROUP BY 1`.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: thanks for the comment. I have made an edit that reflects your comment. BTW, if there are multiple values in the `profile.foo` the counts can be performed using a `UNION ALL`

Comment: `UNION ALL`, yes, but much more expensive due to multiple sequential scans.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the Postgres specific parallel `unnest()` for this:

```
SELECT unnest('{win2k,winxp,win2k3,vista,win7,win8,win8.1}'::text[]) AS type
      ,unnest(ARRAY[
          count(some_column ~ '5.0.2195' OR NULL)
         ,count(some_column ~ '5.1.2600' OR NULL)
          .. the rest from your query above ...
       ]) AS ct
FROM   profile.foo
```

Sequence and number of values in both arrays must match.
Related answers with more details (be sure to read up!):

- [Parallel unnest() and sort order in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23830991/parallel-unnest-and-sort-order-in-postgresql/23838131#23838131)
- [Is there something like a zip() function in PostgreSQL that combines two arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414750/is-there-something-like-a-zip-function-in-postgresql-that-combines-two-arrays/12414884#12414884)

#### Alternative counting technique (optional)

`count()` only counts non-null values..

```
(TRUE  OR NULL) IS TRUE  
(FALSE OR NULL) IS NULL  
(NULL  OR NULL) IS NULL
```

Voilá. Only `TRUE` is counted. [More details in this answer on dba.SE.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27558/for-absolute-performance-is-sum-faster-or-count/27572#27572)

Aside: Using [**`~`** instead of **`~*`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25779596/regex-and-textmatching-issue/25779834#25779834) in the expressions, since there are no case sensitive letters in these string literals. But I doubt you need a regular expression match at all.

Also, the column names `profile.foo` don't make sense, since the only table is named `foo`, not `profile`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using conditional aggregates, just use `CASE` to populate the `Type` appropriately then group on `Type`:

```
   ;with cte AS (Select   case when profile.foo ~* '5.0.2195' then 'Win2k'
                               when profile.foo ~* '5.1.2600' then 'WinXP' 
                               when profile.foo ~* '5.2.3790' then 'W2k3'
                               when profile.foo ~* '6.0.6000' or profile.foo ~* '6.0.6001' or profile.foo ~* '6.0.6002' then 'Vista'
                               when (profile.foo ~* '6.1.7600' or profile.foo ~* '6.1.7601') then 'Win7'
                               when profile.foo ~* '6.2.9200' then 'Win8'
                               when (profile.foo ~* '6.3.9200' or profile.foo ~* '6.3.9600') then 'Win8.1'
                          end as Type
                 From profile.foo)
    SELECT Type,COUNT(*) AS ct
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY Type
```

Not 100% on postgresql syntax, but the logic is compatible.

Comment: A `CASE` statement produces exactly 1 match per row, while in the original query each row could match multiple expressions. (Illegal column name in the Q aside.) Probably not intended by the author, but still potentially distinct results.

Comment: I ran this and got: ERROR:  
schema "profile" does not exist
LINE 9: From profile.flavor)
             ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: schema "profile" does not exist
SQL state: 3F000
Character: 914

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter None of the criteria overlaps between `CASE` statements in the original query, so counts will be equivalent to what I've done here, just as rows instead of columns, barring syntax issues, of course.

Comment: @BooneStars I don't know offhand what's causing that error, I'm not very familiar with postgresql syntax.

Comment: This is a logic error. Conditions don't have to overlap. A single string can match any number regular expressions, especially since they are not anchored. Consider the value '5.0.2195 5.1.2600'. I am dropping this now. There is too much floating around that does not add up.

Comment: Not referring to the syntax error, which is the OP's doing. (Illegal table or column name.)